# How To Make Android Based Smartphone Consume Less Mobile Internet Bandwidth?

Tags: data-connection, bandwidth

**Control**

I want to have full control over applications and have them ask whether or not i allow them to access mobile internet. I also want to disable automatic updates but enable updates notifications to i can know if update is available and deside to update or not.

**Bandwidth Optimization**

What is appropriate browser that consumes less bandwidth but at the same time still delivers satisfying experience and compatibility with websites?

**Internet Usage Profile**

Is there a way to set custom profile for smartphone when connected with specific connection method? Example:

***1st Internet Data Plan***

If i connect with Wi-Fi the apps and services are allowed full unrestricted internet access.

***2nd Internet Data Plan***

If i connect through mobile internet, everything has limited access - apps, syncronization, background services etc. And requires permission from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Droidwall](http://www.appbrain.com/app/droidwall-android-firewall/com.googlecode.droidwall.free) is what you want! It allows you to control which apps can and cannot access the internet, and the new version (the one i linked) enables data types, so you can allow an app to access the internet all the time, just on 3g, just on Wifi, or never.

Comment: Unfortunately it requires root. I just bought device and rooting will void warranty.

Comment: As a reassurance, i have an HTC EVO, rooted. i have had it rooted since i got it, and have utilized my carrier (Sprint) repairs and replacements without problem. i usually unroot it when i bring it to them, but a few times i've left it, and they haven't said anything yet. Personally, i find reinstalling everything after maintenance worth the root, but i can understand if you wouldn't want to.

Comment: Good news! If you have Sprint, rooting is irrelevant, they'll still repair/replace your phone and give you technical support, even if you're rooted!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that is left up to the applications themselves and as we have seen not all apps have been designed to that level of user friendliness. I have seen it in some app ex. "Only sync when on wifi" or "What time would you like to sync". You could try to use an application like Tasker to turn your 3g off and on at different times.

I know I run my phone at max battery saver mode with turns data off after 15 minutes. Which helps a little.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Opera (either Mini or Mobile) compresses data on their servers before sending it to your phone, so that would use less bandwidth than uncompressed data.  Otherwise there's not much you can do, any good browser downloads exactly what the website tells it to and nothing more.

The DroidWall app might provide some of the functionality you want.  I'm not sure if it allows different profiles for Wi-Fi vs 3G.

Answer (score 2):

In ICS and above, there is a data-limiter that can be used to restrict/throttle the data coming out of the handset (Settings > Data usage), have a look at [this](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/22583/android-ics-control-limit-data-usage/) to see how it works.

But if you're on GB or earlier - maybe [watchdog 3g](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog) would be a better bet fit for your needs.